# Unsigned long long Fibonacci numbers negative?

Tags: c++, unsigned-integer, negative-integer

I've written a simple Fibonacci sequence generator that looks like:

```
#include <iostream>

void print(int c, int r) {
    std::cout << c << "\t\t" << r << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    unsigned long long int a = 0, b = 1, c = 1;
    for (int r = 1; r <= 1e3; r += 1) {
        print(c, r);
        a = b;
        b = c;
        c = a + b;
    }
}
```

However, as `r` gets around the value of 40, strange things begin to happen. `c`'s value oscillate between negative and positive, despite the fact he's an `unsigned` integer, and of course the Fibonacci sequence can't be exactly that.

What's going on with `unsigned long long` integers?

Does `c` get too large even for a `long long` integer?

Comment: So you are planning to store 1000th fibonacci number in a (possibly) 64 bit number? 1000th fibonacci number FYI is: 43466557686937456435688527675040625802564660517371780402481729089536555417949051890403879840079255169295922593080322634775209689623239873322471161642996440906533187938298969649928516003704476137795166849228875. You should use some custom bigint data type.

Comment: If this is an option, python is a good language choice because it has builtin bigint support.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a narrowing conversion here `print(c, r);` where you defined `print` to take only `int`'s and here you pass an `unsigned long long`. It is implementation defined.

Quoting the C++ Standard Draft:

> [4.4.7:3:](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.integral#3) If the destination type is signed, the value is
>   unchanged if it can be represented in the destination type; otherwise,
>   the value is implementation-defined.

But what typically happens is that: from the `unsigned long long`, only the bits that are just enough to fit into an `int` are copied to your function. The *truncated* `int` is stored in [Twos complements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement), depending on the value of the [Most Significant Bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_significant_bit). you get such alternation.

Change your function signature to capture `unsigned long long`

```
void print(unsigned long long c, int r) {
    std::cout << c << "\t\t" << r << std::endl;
}
```

---

*BTW, see [Mohit Jain's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37583431/unsigned-long-long-fibonacci-numbers-negative/37583477?noredirect=1#comment62653206_37583431) to your question.*

Comment: @user6245072 To not feel stupid you should start reading compiler warnings.